# No results found on related gridview

Tags: gridview, yii, foreign-keys, relation

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm('','post',array('id'=>'base-si-received-item-form'));?><?php 
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'base-si-received-item-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$searchModel->search(),
    //'filter'=>$searchModel,
    'columns'=>array(       
        array(
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'id'=>'base-si-received-item-id',       
            'selectableRows'=>2, // multiple rows can be selected       
        ),      
        array(
            'name' => 'details.stockno',
            'header'=>'Stock No',
            'value' => '$data->details->stockno',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'details.details_description_search',
            'header'=>'Description',
            'value' => '$data->details->details_description_search',
        ),
```

my model

```
public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.      
    return array(
        'details' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'BaseRefSiDetails', 'details_id'),
    );
}
```

i already tried a lot of approach but none of them works .. what i need is to show datas from a another model the relationship is already done with the help of gii generator but still no results found im stuck .

Comment: Does it work if you just echo out `$model->details->details_description_search` somewhere else in your application?

Comment: i had an error saying Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: It is almost certainly your relation then. Try doing a `print_r($model->details);` (somewhere where you have a single model which definitely has a details record associated with it) and play around with your relation until you get a result. Check [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) for some help

Comment: where should i put print_r($model->details);

Comment: Your models view would be the easiest because it would already have selected a model. Otherwise make a new action and put in something like: `$model = ModelName::model()->find("id = '1'"); print_r($model->details);`. Make sure the id of the model you're selecting exists, and it has a details record associated with it, and change `ModelName` to your models name

Comment: do you think i rather use joining instead of relation

Comment: Up to you, the relations does the same thing "behind the scenes" really. Did you have no luck with my last comment?

Comment: yup .. i can send you my view and model you like

Comment: Cool, you can get my email from my profile

Comment: i already sent all of the files needed